# How to double tap to trigger an event in IONIC 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, ionic4

I am following this tutorial on double tapping a post to create an event in Ionic 4.

https://medium.com/@JordanBenge/ionic-4-quickly-add-ux-through-the-use-of-double-taps-5f6e3216a289,

I have followed the tutorial, by installing hammer JS. 
Importing it into main.ts

```
import 'hammerjs'
```

my app module looks like this,

```
import { AngularFireFunctionsModule, FunctionsRegionToken } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { DoubleTapDirective } from './directives/double-tap.directive'

export class CustomHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  overrides = {
    'press': {time: 500},  // default: 251 ms
    'pinch': {enable: false},
    'rotate': {enable: false},
  };
} 
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, DoubleTapDirective],
  // declarations: [AppComponent, NewTaskModalPage],
  // entryComponents: [NewTaskModalPage],

  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    BrowserModule,

  providers: [
    Camera,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
 {provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: CustomHammerConfig},
 ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Double Tap Directive

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[doubleTapable]'
})
export class DoubleTapDirective {

  @Output() doubleTap = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() tripleTap = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  @HostListener('tap',  ['$event'])
  onTap(e) {
    if (e.tapCount === 2) this.doubleTap.emit(e);
    if (e.tapCount === 3) this.tripleTap.emit(e);
  }
}
```

Now, I have tried to implement this tutorial into my app, where the user double taps on the post in the feed and can add to their favorites. 
With the following code, but this is not working because, when I double tap, the view goes into the PostID details page straight away. It doesn't create the doSomething() event.

Tab4.html

```
<div  (doubleTap)="doSomething()"  id ="post" *ngIf="posts" >
          <!-- [routerLink]="['/tabs/details-feed/', post.postID]"> -->
        <ion-card *ngFor ="let post of posts" [routerLink]="['/tabs/details-feed/', post.postID]">
        <div id ="profileImage" >
           <img id ="profileImageIn" [src]="post.profileImage">
          </div> 
          <div  id ="userName" ><h6>{{post.username}}</h6></div>
          <img [src]="post.image">
        <!-- <div class="card-title">{{post.title}}</div> -->
        </ion-card>
         </div>
```

Tab4.ts

```
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';

 constructor(
    private aff: AngularFireFunctions,
    public toastController: ToastController
    ) {
  async  doSomething() {
      const toast = await this.toastController.create({
        message: 'Added to favorites.',
        duration: 2000
      });
      toast.present();
    }
```

How can I implement the double tap event successfully?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that you have the router configured on the element that is the child of your tappable - see routerLink below:

```
<ion-card *ngFor ="let post of posts" [routerLink]="['/tabs/details-feed/', post.postID]">
```

The way the mouse or touch events stack works (let's skip assumption that this might use [pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events)) is that when user interacts with your component the low-level events will be firing first (touch/mousedown etc) and more complex events that derive out of combination of low-level events will fire last (click):

- touchstart
- touchmove
- touchend / touchcancel
- mouseover
- mousemove
- mousedown
- mouseup
- click

Now "tap" is not official event that browsers recognize (nor double tap). All such tap events are "recognized" by hammer.js library.

So in your case to be able to work with tap / double tap events you need to remove router link as it relies on way lower level event that will always fire even before hammer.js double tap recognizer kicks in.

Instead of routerlink you would need to implement logic that "awaits" for double tap to take place and if after first tap the pause is too long -> then you call router to direct user to the detail page.

See this generic example by hammer: https://codepen.io/jtangelder/pen/pBuIw

Hope this helps.